# Подсчет медианы в группах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Есть датафрейм, в котором каждый из курсов "Title" разбит на модули "module_title". Каждый из модулей "module_title" содержит в себе "lesson_count" уроков.

```
main.groupby(['title','module_title']).agg(lesson_count = ('lesson_number','max'))
```

Датасет выглядит следующим образом:

```
    title      module_title                                     lesson_count
    Excel  Базовый  Визуализация данных Excel                                   5
           Основной функционал Excel                                            11
           Основной функционал Excel (продолжение)                              7
           Сводные таблицы Excel                                                5
           Формулы и функции Excel. Более сложные формулы                       5
    ... ... ...
Руководитель digital-проектов   Решение факапов. Lean/TOC. Обзор.               5
           Требовательность digital-продюсера                                   4
           Управление временем                                                  4
           Управление дизайнерами. Разработка дизайна по scrum                  7
           Экологичный путь менеджера                                           4
```

Необходимо посчитать медианное "lesson_count" для каждого "Title".

Мой код

```
main.groupby(['title']).agg(lesson_count_median = ('lesson_number','median'))
```

дает не совсем то, а именно медиану по множеству номеров уроков для всех модулей "module_title" конкретного курса "Title".

**Желаемый результат:** в "lesson_cout_median" для "Excel-базовый" должно выводиться 5 (а не 4), а для "Руководитель digital-проектов" - 4 (а не 3) и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на датасет.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rIPPjZC2XWsUavq3BiJspH_pggxIf_xG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Включите в вопрос воспроизводимый пример данных, замените скриншоты на текстовые выводы и приведите пример желаемого результата.

Comment: @strawdog, Датасет добавил, желаемые результат - над вторым скриншотом. Скриншоты не убрал, так как они - нагляднее всего.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста игрушечный пример входных данных на 5-10 строк (а не на 127 MB) и результат, который вы хотите получить...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv("main.csv", sep=";", index_col=0)

res = (df
       .groupby(['title','module_title'])
       ["lesson_number"]
       .nunique()
       .groupby("title")
       .median())
```

результат:

```
In [220]: res
Out[220]:
title
Excel Базовый                           5
Java-разработчик                        7
Java-разработчик c нуля                10
JavaScript с нуля                       7
PHP-разработчик с 0 до PRO. Часть 1     4
SMM-маркетолог от А до Я                6
UX-дизайн                               4
Анимация интерфейсов                    3
Веб-вёрстка для начинающих 2.0          7
Веб-дизайн PRO 2.0                      5
Веб-дизайн Базовый                      3
Веб-дизайн с нуля 2.0                   4
Веб-разработчик                         2
Интернет-маркетолог от Ingate           7
Руководитель digital-проектов           5
Name: lesson_number, dtype: int64
```